# Vibration when applying brake

Tags: toyota

Good day, please i am using a 2003 toyota Camry le v6,i purchased it around January 2020. When i apply the brake the car vibrate and i can feel on the Steering wheel. I was told to change the rotor, brake pads and did wheel balancing as well, still the same result i had to change the rotor, brake pads and wheel balancing again, when i apply the brake at 60 m/h i feel the vibration but any thing above or below 60 i don't feel the vibration and i have been to 2 good mechanics but it not fixed. Please what can be wrong

Comment: Check the wheel bearings.

Comment: If the wheel bearings are good, use a dial indicator and check the rotor runout. If it is over .002" then you know what direction to go to find the cause. Remember that the hub that the rotor sets on must be immaculately clean as well as the wheels where they meet the rotor and lug nuts must be at the proper torque.